# Tablesorter not sorting millions

Tags: sorting

I'm building a mobile real estate website for my wife's business using Tablesorter to sort by price.  It works fine for 6 digit numbers (including $s and commas), e.g. $600,000.  However it fails when confronting a 7 digit number, e.g. $1,295,000.

In my

```
    <script type="text/javascript" id="js">$(document).ready(function() {
$("table").tablesorter({
    // sort on the second column, order asc
    sortList: [[1,0]],
    headers: {
 1: { sorter: 'digit' } // column number, type
    }
});
```

});

```
<table cellspacing="2" class="tablesorter { 0: { sorter: false}, 1: {sorter: true} }">
            <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="158" class="headerempty">Property</th>
            <th width="130" class="{'sorter':'currency'}">Sort by Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td><img src="../sales/29 Laurel Way/prepped_images/29lw-for_mobile.jpg" title="Tap for Details" alt="29 Laurel Way" width="150" height="100" border="0"></td>
        <td class="{'sorter':'currency'}">$329,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td><img src="../sales/Aetna Lane/al_for_Mobile.jpg" width="150" height="100"></td>
        <td class="{'sorter':'currency'}">$175,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td><img src="../sales/Atop Smith Hill/prepped/ash_mobile.jpg" width="150" height="100"></td>
        <td class="{'sorter':'currency'}">$1,295,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td><img src="../sales/Beech Hill/bh_mobile.jpg" width="150" height="100"></td>
        <td class="{'sorter':'currency'}">$595,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="{'sorter':'currency'}"><img src="../sales/Bluefield/b_mobile.jpg" width="150" height="100"></td>
        <td>$299,000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Any thoughts on solving this one?  Many thanks in advance, clpix

Answer (score 1):

Constructions like `td class="{'sorter':'currency'}"` make me scary. You probaly should define table with class sortable and init table sorted in `JS` using this class, and define sorting parameters in constructor:

```
$(".sortable").tablesorter({
// sort on the second column, order asc
sortList: [[1,0]],
headers: {
    1: { sorter: 'currency' } // column number, type
}
});
<table class='sortable'>
    <tr>
        <td>$1.000.000</td>
    </tr>
    ......
</table>
```

And check out delimeter `.` or `,`

[This code work](http://paste.org.ru/?9ejmuw) fine.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  However, my prices in the millions are still sorting incorrectly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Use ',' instead of '.' in digit delimiter. [Working example](http://paste.org.ru/?9ejmuw)

Comment: Jeka,  Thanks for the working example!  Solved my problem.  I'm very grateful.  Best, clpix